# woh to send a email in node js and express js by nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I want to send an email in experss project. Using nodemailer. But I get the following error
{
"errno": -4078,
"code": "ECONNECTION",
"syscall": "connect",
"address": "127.0.0.1",
"port": 25,
"command": "CONN"
}

The image below is related to the codes

Comment: Please share the code, we can not determine the problem without code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see that issue is occurring with your port number and also it occur with the sender you are using for it like sendgrid or sendinblue or gmail cause some of them are not supported localhost or http request and it also depends on what port are you using for that try to change that for mails you can use 465,524 also